# heavy mysql views break phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have some very useful views in my mysql database.

Some of them take a while to run (up to 6 minutes), which is fine with me.  They are used for things like end-of-day reports.

phpMyAdmin likes to display record count and other statistics when rendering it's various displays... Which requires the views query to be run, and causes a php execution timout.... Making phpmyadmin unusable (not to mention the cpu time lost calculating the number of rows in a view that I have no need to run at the moment).

Is there a way to turn off these extraneous table (in my case view) statistics to make phpMyAdmin useable again?

Comment: Have you tried adding appropriate indexes on the tables you are querying for your views so as to make the queries run in an appropriate amount of time?  Alternatively, have you tried to increase your php timeout value in php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest dropping your use of PhpMyAdmin and using something like the below, I stopped using PhpMyAdmin a few years ago and never looked back.

Mysql Workbench: http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ (Free)

SQLYog: http://www.webyog.com/en/ (Paid, but worth it - amazing utility)

Comment: http://www.heidisql.com/ is also a good alternative thats free (and open source for those who like that).

Comment: Thanks for these alternatives.  Do you happen to know how they work with high-latency connections?  I'm about 200ms away from my databases.

Comment: I couldn't comment specifically, but I've connected to our servers in the states under heavy load (when something's gone wrong) and had no problems connecting with either SQLYog (windows) or Workbench (mac). My only gripe for SQLYog is no Mac support, whilst Workbench is amazing and for designing your schema it's second to none, the query interface is a little clunky at times (still better than phpmyadmin though IMO!)

Comment: The schema designer in Workbench is fantastic by the way and I couldn't recommend it enough http://www.mysql.com/common/images/products/MySQL_Workbench_Visual_Design_Mac.gif

Answer (score 0):

Eric,

I believe the latest version of phpMyAdmin4.0.1 beta can circumvent this issue... sort of.  You can navigate to the table you need in the left panel without loading the right pane (which loads on count on all tables) including heavy views.

I use phpMyAdmin as a simple reporting tool for business users, so this latest release is nice because they can get to the view they want without waiting for the right pane to load.

I agree with Williamvicary, that if you're just doing devepment, get a better tool.  SQLYog is awesome (even the community version). And SequelPro if you are on Mac.