# phpmyadmin and views

Tags: phpmyadmin

In my database when I use phpmyadmin and click to view the second page of tables it takes a long time (1min roughly) to appear.

I believe the cause of this is the views in the database. I give them all a v which pushes them all to the second page but something must be happening to make it take so long to generate the list?

This post seems to be discussing the same issue:
[heavy mysql views break phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850158/heavy-mysql-views-break-phpmyadmin)

Is there a way to get phpmysql to just display the views in the list?

Thanks,

Mat

Answer (score 0):

```
In my database when I use phpmyadmin and click to view the second page
 of tables it take a long time (1min roughly) to appear.
```

When you click to view next page (or for that matter anyother page ) ,you are not creating or  viewing any views.You are simply limiting your query to reduce the number of tuples being displayed.

**For Example:**
Generally phpmyadmin limits no. of tuples to 30.So whenever you type a query phpmyadmin appends LIMIT 0,30 to the query and runs it. If you press on the second page ,essentially the same query is executed but this time it is appended with LIMIT 30,30.

However in case of Views the time taken to execute depends of the complexity of the query used in creating the view.Try refactoring and forming a better query for faster results